# Applying square bullets in css affects numbers

Tags: html, css

When I use this in my css to achieve square bullets:

```
li { list-style-type: square; }
```

it affects all numbered lists as well, as they both use `<li>`

The context is within a sharepoint richhtmlfield control.

Is there a way around this or have Microsoft not implemented numbered lists correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the parent of the `<li>`s to apply the styles to, thus only affecting unordered lists (`<ul>`):

```
ul li { list-style-type: square; }
```

Comment: That won't work with an ol inside a ul. I'd suggest using ul {}.